# Getting Browser URL in Node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, url

I was looking to get the browser url from a user who has included my external js file in their website. They include the js file, which makes an ajax call using jquery to my node server. I know I could pass the url to my server by getting it with javascript and sending it with the ajax call, but I assume this would be a security risk since it's easy to fake the url. I have the same security issue by looking at the header. Does anyone know how to get the url sercurely to the server? I'm using node.js and express for my server.

Comment: 1. How is that a "security risk"? what damage could be done? 2. I might be proven wrong, but off the top of my head I don't think it's possible

Comment: Every bit of the request can be faked in one way or another. It sounds like you're trying to distribute a .js file that you only want to be used by certain websites. There are a few things that you can do to make it harder to get around, but none of them are able to prevent someone from using their own server as a proxy and faking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trust the person controlling the client then you can use the `referer` header, but note that it is sometimes suppressed by the browser to protect the user's privacy.

If you control the server hosting the HTML then you can have that server generate a psuedo-random token, send it to the server hosting the JS with the URL for the HTML, then embed that token in query string for the `<script>` element that it embeds in the HTML before delivering that HTML to the client.

Otherwise, there is no entity that you trust to tell you the truth about the URL and you are stuck.